# If $f(x)=\langle x,a\rangle e^{-\langle x, x\rangle} \ \forall x, a \in \Bbb{R}^{n}$, then prove that $f$ is of class $C^{1}$ and compute $f'(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ be a function defined by

$$f(x) = \langle x, a \rangle e^{-\langle x, x\rangle}$$

$\forall x \in \Bbb{R}^n, \ a \in \Bbb{R}^{n}$.

**Questions:** I want to

1. Prove that $f$ is of class $C^{1}$
2. Compute $f'(x)$ for any $x\in\Bbb{R}^n$

**I started by using definition:**

Let $x, a, h \in\Bbb{R}^{n}$, then

\begin{align}
f(x+h)-f(x) &= \langle x + h, a \rangle e^{-\langle x+h, x+h \rangle} - \langle x, a\rangle e^{-\langle x, x \rangle} \\
&= \left[ \langle x, a \rangle + \langle h, a \rangle \right] e^{-\langle x, x \rangle - \langle x, h \rangle - \langle h, x \rangle - \langle h, h \rangle} - \langle x, a \rangle e^{-\langle x, x \rangle}
\end{align}

But I don't know how to proceed from here. Please, could anyone help out?

Comment: To prove that is $C^1$ it's enough to say that is a product and composition of $C^1$ functions.

Comment: @Graham Kemp: Thanks a lot for the edit!

Comment: Do you mean $\nabla f(x)$ by $f'(x)$?

Comment: @Mostafa Ayaz: I don't think so. $f$ should be in $\Bbb{R}$

Comment: But it is multivariate and we need to take derivation of $f$ respect to each of $x_i$s...

Comment: @Mostafa Ayaz: As you know, you are far more experienced than me. You are right! I forgot! So, we should have $f'(x)(h)=\langle \nabla f(x),h\rangle$

Comment: Thank you but i don't think to be that experienced. I just suspected that part of the question. Nice editing... (+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\<}{\langle}\newcommand{\>}{\rangle}$I think you want to show differentiability using the definition, right? What is the definition of differentiability? $f$ is said to be differentiable in $x$, if there exists $L(x)$ such that as $h\to 0$:
\begin{align}\tag{1}
f(x+h)=f(x)+\<L(x), h\>+o(h)
\end{align}
Moreover if such $L$ exists then $\nabla f(x)=L(x)$.

First notice that:
\begin{align}e^{-\<x+h,x+h \>}&=e^{-\<x,x\>-2\<x,h\>-\<h,h \>}\\
&=e^{-\<x,x\>}\left( e^{-2\<x,h\>-\<h,h \>}\right)\\
&\stackrel{*}{=}e^{-\<x,x\>}\left(1-2\<x,h\>-\<h,h \>+o(h)\right)\\
&=e^{-\<x,x\>}-2\<x,h\>e^{-\<x,x\>}+o(h)
\end{align}
where we have used the power series of the exponential function in $(*)$ which will be proven at the end. This means that:

\begin{align}
f(x+h)&=\<x+h,a\>e^{-\<x+h,x+h \>}\\&=\<x+h,a\>\left(e^{-\<x,x\>}-2\<x,h\>e^{-\<x,x\>}+o(h)\right)\\
&=\left(\<x,a\>+\<h,a\>\right)\left(e^{-\<x,x\>}-2\<x,h\>e^{-\<x,x\>}+o(h)\right)\\
&=\<x,a\>e^{-\<x,x\>}-2\<x,a\>\<x,h\>e^{-\<x,x\>}+\<h,a\>e^{-\<x,x\>}+o(h)\\
&=f(x)+e^{-\<x,x\>}\left( \< h,a\>-2\<x,a\>\<x,h\>\right)+o(h)\\
&=f(x)+ \< h,\left(a-2\<x,a\>x\right)e^{-\<x,x\>}\>+o(h)\\
\end{align}
Comparing what we have now with $(1)$ it is clear that $L(x)$ exists, hence:
\begin{align}
\nabla f(x)=\left(a-2\<x,a\>x\right)e^{-\<x,x\>}
\end{align}
Using a similar method, you can show that $\nabla f(x+h)\to\nabla f(x)$ as $h\to 0$ to conclude that $\nabla f$ is continuous... Or you could also check if $\nabla f(x)$ is continuous componentwise (because that implies continuity of $\nabla f$ as well). I leave that up to you.

---

**Proof of ($*$).**

\begin{align}
e^{-2\<x,h\>-\<h,h\>} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-2\<x,h\>-\<h,h\>)^k}{k!}=1-2\<x,h\>-\<h,h\>+\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-2\<x,h\>-\<h,h\>)^k}{k!}
\end{align}
Let $h\in \bar B_1(0)$ i.e. the closed unit ball. Then of course the map  $$h\mapsto -2\<x,h\>-\<h,h\>$$ is bounded (why?). That means that 
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-2\<x,h\>-\<h,h\>)^k}{k!}
\end{align}
converges uniformly for $h\in \bar B_1(0)$. So you can prove that:
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0 } \frac{\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-2\<x,h\>-\<h,h\>)^k}{k!}}{\Vert h\Vert} =\sum_{k=2}^\infty \lim_{h\to 0 }\frac{(-2\<x,h\>-\<h,h\>)^k}{\Vert h\Vert k!}= 0
\end{align}
to conclude:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-2\<x,h\>-\<h,h\>)^k}{k!}= o(h)
\end{align}

Comment: How did you get \begin{align}
&=e^{-\<x,x\>}\left(1-2\<x,h\>-\<h,h \>+o(h)\right)?\\
\end{align}

Comment: It is a standard consequence of the power series of $e^x$. Edited the answer to include that, I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 2):

As you've written \begin{align}
f(x+h)-f(x) &= \langle x + h, a \rangle e^{-\langle x+h, x+h \rangle} - \langle x, a\rangle e^{-\langle x, x \rangle} \\
&= \left[ \langle x, a \rangle + \langle h, a \rangle \right] e^{-\langle x, x \rangle - \langle x, h \rangle - \langle h, x \rangle - \langle h, h \rangle} - \langle x, a \rangle e^{-\langle x, x \rangle}\\&=e^{-\langle x,x\rangle}\left(\langle x, a \rangle \left[e^{-2\langle x,h \rangle-\langle h,h\rangle}-1\right]+\langle h,a\rangle e^{-2\langle x,h \rangle-\langle h,h\rangle}\right)
\end{align}
notice that $\langle x,x\rangle$ is constant and we can make $-2\langle x,h\rangle-\langle h,h\rangle$ and $\langle h,a\rangle$ arbitrarily near to zero therefore $f(x+h)-f(x)$ can be arbitrarily bounded by proper choice of $h$ (this argument can be made more precise later) therefore $f(x)$ is continuous. The same argument can help us prove the 1st-order partial differentiability of the function. To show the differentiability of $f(x)$ respect to $x_i$ we need to show that the following function $$(a_ix_i+C)e^{-x_i^2+D}$$is differentiable respect to $x_i$ where$$C=a_2x_2+\cdots +a_nx_n\\D=-x_2^2-\cdots -x_n^2$$but this is simple since both $e^{-x_i^2+D}$ and $a_ix_i+C$ are differentiable respect to $x_i$ so will be their multiplication which completes our proof on 1st-order differentiability. We know that $$f(x)=f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=(x_1a_1+\cdots+x_na_n)e^{-x_1^2-\cdots-x_n^2}$$therefore $$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=a_ie^{-x_1^2-\cdots-x_n^2}-2x_i(x_1a_1+\cdots+x_na_n)e^{-x_1^2-\cdots-x_n^2}$$where we can write$$\nabla f(x)=\left(a-2\langle x,a\rangle x\right)e^{-\langle x,x\rangle}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Now, I have many things to look at!

Comment: Mmm, but when does existence of partial derivatives imply differentiability?

Comment: Actually never It does. If you can prove that a function is continuous and differentiable then you are allowed to use the usual rules of differentiation for functions. In fact when considering one variable in your partial differentiation you can treat the others as constants. Here for example for checking the existence of partial derivation respect to $x_1$ you need to check whether $(a_1x_1+C)e^{-x_1^2+D^2}$ is continuous and differentiable or not where $$C=a_2x_2+\cdots +a_nx_n\\D=-x_2^2-\cdots -x_n^2$$which is the same as for single variable case.

Comment: I don't see how that adresses my question... The OP wants to prove differentiability, but I don't see where you talk about it in your answer.

Comment: I added more details hope it helps now

Answer (score 1):

Not only is $f$ is of class $C^{1}$ it is smooth: it has derivatives of all orders. This follows from the fact that compositions of smooth maps are smooth. To find the derivative if $f$ is is enough to compute its partial derivatives. [ The derivative is a linear map from $\mathbb R ^{n} \to \mathbb R$ and its matrix is simply the vector of partial derivatives]. Computation of partial derivatives is very easy so I will leave that to you.

Comment: Dear Sir, I am new into this course. How do I get the partial derivative of inner products? Kindly help Sir!

Comment: $\langle x,a \rangle =\sum x_ia_i$ so the partial derivatives are $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$. Also $\langle x,x \rangle =\sum x_i^{2}$ and  partial derivatives are $2x_1,2x_2,...,2x_n$.

Comment: Ooh, that's it!

Answer (score 1):

Lets express $f$ as explicitly;

$$f(x_1,...,x_n) = [x_1*a_1 + x_2*a_2 + ... + x_n * a_n] * e^{-x_1^2} * e^{-x_2^2} * ... * e^{-x_n^2}.$$

Now, for each variable $x_i$, $f$ has the form
$$f(x_1,...,x_n) = [x_i*a_i + c_1] * e^{-x_i^2} * c_2,\quad \text{for some constants } c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}.$$

It is clear that since $f$ is a product of degree 1 polynomial with the exponential function, each of which is class of $C^\infty$, $f$ is also of class $C^\infty$.

Now, to find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$, from the above representation of $f$, it is clear that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}|_{(x_1, ...,x_n)} = a_i * c_2 * e^{-x_i^2} + [x_i*a_i + c_1] * c_2 * (-2 x_i) * e^{-x_i^2} \\
= a_i * [\prod_{j=1}^n e^{-x_j^2}] + [x_i*a_i + c_1] * [\prod_{j=1}^n e^{-x_j^2}]*(-2 x_i)$$